# Is there any way to do X.509 Certificate creation in .net?

Tags: .net, security, x509certificate2

I take some days and still can not find any way to do X.509 Certificate creation in .net.
Is there anyone who can give me an answer or some hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at that very helpful library: http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp

Comment: so you mean there is no any class in .net base library for creating x.509 certificate?

Thanks